# what is the amplitude and argument of given z= 1-cos(9$\pi$/10)-i*sin(9$\pi$/10)

Tags: complex-numbers

What is the amplitude and argument of the given complex number below?

> $ z= 1-\cos(9\pi/10)-i \cdot\sin(9\pi/10)$

I have tried this a few times but the answer won't match
the answer to this problem which is $-\pi/20$ for the argument.

This is my solution:

[image]

Comment: Try drawing a picture.

Comment: solution needed i need to know process ,drawing a graph is just brute force

Answer (score 1):

$1-e^{i\theta}=e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}} e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}}-e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}} e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}$
$= -e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}(e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}- e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}})=-2i\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}} e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}.$

$z=1-e^{\frac{9i\pi}{10}}=-2i\sin{\frac{9\pi}{20}}e^{\frac{9i\pi}{20}}.$

Hence the magnitude is $ 2\sin{\frac{9\pi}{20}}$ and the argument $-\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{9\pi}{20}=\frac{-\pi}{20}$

Comment: explain 4th step

Comment: $e^{i \phi} =\cos(\phi)+i \sin(\phi) $ and $ e^{-i \phi}=\cos(\phi) - i \sin(\phi)$ so $e^{i \phi} - e^{-i \phi} = 2i \sin(\phi) $

Answer (score 0):

Draw a picture in the complex plane of a triangle with one vertex at $0$, one at $1$ and one at $\cos{{9\pi\over10}}+i\sin{{9\pi\over10}}$  Do you see it now?

Comment: expain please now i am interested in answer with a possibility of graph moreover a new way for me as i ahvent tried suchq with graphs

Comment: also explain when its favorable to use graph

Comment: The angle at the origin is ${9\pi\over10}$  The triangle is isosceles, so the other two angles are ${\pi\over20}$  The segment joining $1$ and $\cos{{9\pi\over10}}+i\sin{{9\pi\over10}}$ is just a translate of the segment joining $0$ and $1-\cos{{9\pi\over10}}-i\sin{{9\pi\over10}}$  Draw the picture and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\theta=9\pi/20$ so $$z=1-\cos 2\theta-i\sin 2\theta =2\sin\theta (\sin\theta -i\cos\theta)=-2i\sin\theta\exp i\theta,$$which has modulus $|2\sin\theta|$ and argument $\theta-\frac{\pi}{2}\operatorname{sign}\sin\theta$. For the problem at hand, $\operatorname{sign}\sin\theta=1$.

Answer (score 0):

If the argument is $\theta$, and the point is in the fourth quadrant so $\theta = \arctan \frac{-\sin \frac {9}{10}\pi}{1 - \cos \frac 9{10}{\pi}}$  which if one is too lazy to do trig you can just punch into a calculator to get is $-.05 \pi$.

Or I could remember my trig identities.

$1-\cos \frac 9{10}\pi = 1-\cos 2\frac 9{20}\pi = 1 - \cos^2 \frac 9{20}\pi + \sin^2 \frac 9{20}\pi = 2\sin^2 \frac 9{20}\pi$.

And $\sin \frac 9{10}\pi = \sin 2\frac 9{20}\pi = 2\sin \frac 9{20}\pi\cos \frac 9{20}\pi$.

So $\theta = \arctan \frac{-2\sin \frac 9{20}\pi\cos \frac 9{20}\pi}{ 2\sin^2 \frac 9{20}\pi} = $

$\arctan \frac{-\cos\frac 9{20}\pi}{\sin \frac 9{20}\pi}=$

$\arctan \cot -\frac 9{20}\pi=$

$-(\pi - \frac 9{20}\pi)=-\frac 1{20}\pi$

Or I could draw the picture below.

[image]

Anyway the argument is $-\frac 1{20}\pi$.